# AutoComplete throwing nullpointer when in ui:include code

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, uiinclude

I am using a PrimeFaces autoComplete box in my code. I have used this components in various places in my application with no problem. When I have it in a block of code that is dynamically included via ui:include, I get:

```
14:32:30,115 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] (http-steves-10.11.100.136-15081-2) java.lang.NullPointerException
```

If I take the exact code copy and paste it into the parent right before the ui:include, it works there. So obviously the problem has something to do with it being in the ui:include. Is there a problem with ajax controls in an include? What would I need to work around this?

My environment is PF3.4RC1, JBoss7.1, Mojarra 2.1.5

**Update:**
Here is the code I am using. I haven't bothered including the backing beans because I put breakpoints in that code and it only is touched when I use the "working" autocomplete. As an additional piece of information, I tries putting a commandbutton on the fragment and it too fails to call the actionlistener method on the backing bean.

Main (Parent) page:

```
<p:panel id="dataEntryPane"
    rendered="#{manageItemHandler.currItem ne null}">
    <!-- This Auto Complete works -->
    <p:autoComplete
        completeMethod="#{itemAutoComplete.autoCompleteList}" var="item"
        itemLabel="#{item.itemNum}" itemValue="#{item}"
        converter="ItemConverter" queryDelay="750">

        <f:facet name="itemtip">
        <p:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5" style=" width:400px;">
                <f:facet name="header">
                <p:column colspan="2">
                    <h:outputText value="Item Information"
                         style="font-weight:bold; font-size:20px; font-style:italic;" />
                 </p:column>
                 </f:facet>

             <p:row>
                 <h:outputText value="#{item.itemNum}" />
             </p:row>
             <p:row>
                 <h:outputText value="#{item.itemDesc}" />
             </p:row>
         </p:panelGrid>
     </f:facet>
 </p:autoComplete>


    <ui:include src="#{manageItemHandler.dataEntryFrag}" />
</p:panel>
```

Included Fragment:

```
<p:panel>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Operation - #{manageItemHandler.dataEntryOp.operationNum} BOM Entry" />
        <p:commandButton value="SignOff"
            actionListener="#{manageItemHandler.doSignOff(manageItemHandler.dataEntryOp.bom)}"
            style="float:right"
            rendered="#{speed2Session.isRendered('editManageItemOp')}" />
    </f:facet>

        <!-- This autocomplete does not work -->
    <p:autoComplete completeMethod="#{itemAutoComplete.autoCompleteList}"
        var="item" itemLabel="#{item.itemNum}" itemValue="#{item}"
        converter="ItemConverter" queryDelay="750">

        <f:facet name="itemtip">
            <p:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5" style=" width:400px;">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <p:column colspan="2">
                        <h:outputText value="Item Information" style="font-weight:bold; font-size:20px; font-style:italic;" />
                    </p:column>
                </f:facet>

                <p:row>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.itemNum}" />
                </p:row>

                <p:row>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.itemDesc}" />
                </p:row>
            </p:panelGrid>
        </f:facet>
    </p:autoComplete>

    <p:dataTable id="dt_bom" value="#{manageItemHandler.dataEntryOp.bom}"
        var="bom">
        <p:column headerText="Item Number">
            <p:inputText value="#{bom.component}"
                disabled="#{speed2Session.isDisabled('editManageItemOp')}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Item Description">
            <h:outputText value="#{bom.descrip}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="QTY">
            <p:inputText value="#{bom.qty}"
                disabled="#{speed2Session.isDisabled('editManageItemOp')}"></p:inputText>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
    <p:commandButton value="test button"></p:commandButton>
</p:panel>
```

Unfortunately, the above error is all that I get in the stack trace. Here are a few preceeding lines for completeness. I Typed into the autocomplete box twice in the trace and you can see by the time what was logged when I did.

```
15:58:11,578 INFO  [stdout] (http-steves-10.11.100.136-15081-6) Hibernate: 
15:58:11,578 INFO  [stdout] (http-steves-10.11.100.136-15081-6)     select
15:58:11,579 INFO  [stdout] (http-steves-10.11.100.136-15081-6)         itemdata0_.DESCRIP as col_0_0_ 
15:58:11,579 INFO  [stdout] (http-steves-10.11.100.136-15081-6)     from
15:58:11,580 INFO  [stdout] (http-steves-10.11.100.136-15081-6)         MCSITEM itemdata0_ 
15:58:11,580 INFO  [stdout] (http-steves-10.11.100.136-15081-6)     where
15:58:11,581 INFO  [stdout] (http-steves-10.11.100.136-15081-6)         itemdata0_.ITEM=?

15:58:16,538 INFO  [com.newpig] (http-steves-10.11.100.136-15081-6) In AutoLoginFilter.doFilter
15:58:16,541 INFO  [com.newpig] (http-steves-10.11.100.136-15081-6) In SecurityFilter.doFilter
15:58:16,542 INFO  [com.newpig] (http-steves-10.11.100.136-15081-6) OriginalURL: /speed2/modules/main.faces
15:58:16,575 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] (http-steves-10.11.100.136-15081-6) java.lang.NullPointerException
16:02:43,442 INFO  [com.newpig] (http-steves-10.11.100.136-15081-6) In AutoLoginFilter.doFilter
16:02:43,445 INFO  [com.newpig] (http-steves-10.11.100.136-15081-6) In SecurityFilter.doFilter
16:02:43,446 INFO  [com.newpig] (http-steves-10.11.100.136-15081-6) OriginalURL: /speed2/modules/main.faces
16:02:43,475 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] (http-steves-10.11.100.136-15081-6) java.lang.NullPointerException
```

**UPDATE 2:**
My intention is to dynamically swap out a section of the screen as the user clicks buttons. As a test, I defaulted to the fragment in question (SpecSheet) when the backing bean is created. When I do that, the Autocomplete works for that fragment. When I switch to another fragment(BOM) with an autocomplete, that one doesn't work. If I switch back to SpecSheet, that autocomplete still works.

Comment: A stacktrace would have been helpful.

Comment: Sorry, I should have included my code on the first go-round. As for the stack trace, that error is all that I get. Not much to go on. I have included a few more lines from my log just to show what I am seeing. Thanks.

Comment: Added second update. Did more testing, trying to narrow down the problem. It seems that if the include happens when the page is first rendered, it works. If it is added later via ajax, it does not.